# MySQL Trigger to auto insert week of the year and 001 (autoincrement)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'd like to set a MySQL trigger to set an ID number with the following format:

week of the year + 001

For example 09002 would be the 9th week of the year and 002 would be the second order for that week.

Any help, comment would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

USE CONCAT WITH MYSQL DATE FUNCTION WEEK

```
select CONCAT('0',WEEK(now()),'002');
+-------------------------------+
| CONCAT('0',WEEK(now()),'002') |
+-------------------------------+
| 029002                        |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TEST_INSERT;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER TEST_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON TEST FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     NEW.ID= CONCAT('0',WEEK(now()),'002')
-------------------- your insert statement ----------
    END$$
```

Comment: within the trigger you can add your insert statment

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with a trigger is a problem in MySQL because MySQL doesn't have a SEQUENCE object, like some other SQL databases have. You can't generate an incrementing id value in a trigger, it must be generated to populate an integer column that has the AUTO_INCREMENT option.

So here's an unconventional solution: don't think of using a trigger for this, use the primary key. At the start of each week, run a scheduled job to advance the next auto-increment number.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = WEEK(NOW())*1000;
```

You can do this from a cron job, or you can use the [MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

I would also comment that you can't rely on the incrementing id being consecutive. You could have inserts that fail, or you could have some inserts be part of transactions that roll back, or you could have later deletions. All these would eliminate a row with a certain id value, and you shouldn't re-use id values.